# asp.net mvc3, how do I authenticate?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorize

I need to build a "my account" application for my friend.  I plan to use asp.net MVC 3.

I have to use  third party API to authenticate users.  if this is regular web application, it is easy, I submit the request using third party API, get response back. if this is authorized user, create a session.  ON all the protected pages, i just check the session, if it is exist, then show the content, otherwise redirect back to login page.

I probably can do the same on my mvc3 project, but I know that definitely is a wrong approach.  MVC3 is very flexiable.  there must be a better way to do it.  After I get response back from the third party API.  What should I do after that?  please show me some codes if you can.

Comment: homework? do you know how to use google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ASP.NET membership provider and create a custom provider to hook into your API. This gets a lot of the hard work done for you and you're not "reinventing the wheel". There's a great overview about how to do this with MVC here: http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new MVC 3 application using the "Internet Application" template when you do file-new project.
2. All the code is then created for you - in visual studio click on the "ASP.NET Configuration" icon in solution explorer.
3. create your users and your roles
4. decorate your controllers and/or action methods with

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class MyAdminOnlyController : Controller
{
}
```

1. Configure additional features such as forgotten password functionality, password resets, etc. Some additional features will require coding.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using MVC3 for authentication is anything different than regular web app. In your controller, you will send the username and password getting from the view to the API,getting the response back.

You can then save it to session and check against it on any page you want to be protected.

MVC is just the way to separate view logic, business logic and data model. The application flow is the same.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET already build ASP.NET membership provider. The back end data can be stored in ASP.NET Configuration website, SQL Server database,Active Directory, and another database but you need to custom the authentication provider.

[this is](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) the expample for SQLServer Membership provider, for the detail documentation you can read from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

For ASP.NET Configuration management Membership provider, you can read from [Music Store ASP.NET MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/aspnet-mvc-music-store) in [Membership and Authorization section](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-7). If you want to learn about ASP.NET MVC authentication/authorization. Music Store example is a recommended tutorial for exploring ASP.NET MVC3 feature, Entity Framework and Authentication also.